# Изменение настроек в файле php.ini не меняет настройки php

Tags: php, apache, apache2

Использую apache2 + несколько версий php (5.6, 7.0, 7.3). На сервере два виртуальных хоста. Я изменяю версию php на каждом из хостов путем добавления сл. строчки в конфиги хоста

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/var/www/html
```

phpinfo() на сайте показывает изменение на версию 7.0

так же пхп инфо указывает на сл. файл

```
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
```

Пытаюсь изменить настройки в этом файле, например изменить upload_max_filesize или что угодно, изменения не вступают в силу. При этом если убрать строку

```
 ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/var/www/html
```

из настроек хоста, версия php поднимается до максимальной и файл настроек php лежит в другом месте

```
/etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini
```

При таком раскладе все настройки из этого файла вступают в силу. Подскажите что я делаю не правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. Я перезагружал apache а надо было перезагружать php `/etc/init.d/php7.0-fpm restart`  . Надеюсь это поможет кому-то сэкономить время!